# Going from AZERTY keyboard to QWERTY

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am about to order a laptop online that comes with AZERTY keyboard layout. If I install English US which is the one I prefer to use will it automaticall go to QWERTY or will it remain the same? IF it remains as AZERTY how can I change it to QWERTY?

I will propably be using Win8 or Win10

Comment: Using the US keyboard driver it will become a QWERTY keyboard. But the button labels won't change ;-)

Comment: LOL yeah I can live with the labels not changing :P I can even get stickers if I want to :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify your OS, so I dont know which layout it will be, but I will assume that you are on Windows in case that it doesn't change automatically you can do that like this:

- Go to the Start button and open "Control Panel"
- Choose the option "Clock, Language and Region"
- Select "Regional and Language Options" and in the "Installed
  Services" section, click "Add"
- If your keyboard is set to "French" (AZERTY) change it to "English
  US/UK" and if your keyboard is set to an English language (QWERTY),
  change the language to "French" (AZERTY).
- In the "Keyboard" section, choose "QWERTY" or "AZERTY" and apply the
  changes by clicking "OK"

Comment: ah yes, sorry, Win8

Comment: Pretty much. When I was in france, most cybercafes used to give that option for visiting folks.